# How come I can't load this http module in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, request

```
var http = require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = 99;

    TypeError: Cannot set property 'maxSockets' of undefined
```

I want to se the number of maxSockets to 99, no matter what.  But when I load that line, it says that globalAgent is undefined??

Also - if I put this line of code in my app.js, will it hold throughout my entire project? For example, if I require another module, which that module requires "request" module...and that request module requires http...will it keep maxSockets at 99 because I have this line of code early in my app.js before everything else?

Basically, I want 99 maxSockets for everything in my app.js and all its submodules and all those submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Node.js? Looks like `http.globalAgent` was added in v0.5.3.

The `globalAgent.maxSockets` should be global throughout other modules requiring http.

Also, you probably want to split up setting maxSockets, unless you really want to assign http the value 99.

```
var http = require('http');
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 99;
```

If you don't split up the assignment, you'll have a problem if you try to use the `http` var later, like

```
var http = require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = 99;
http.createServer();
```

Comment: Why can't I set maxSockets to 9999?

Comment: If you're running a version of Node.js >= v0.5.3, then `http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 9999;` should work.

Comment: Most of the time when you do something like `var http = require('http');`, you're expecting the var `http` to be assigned a reference to the http module...   If you do `var http = require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = 99;`, then the var `http` is assigned the value 99.